# How to limit a Qt window in a screen?

Tags: qt

On Widnows or Mac, I can drag a Qt window from one screen to another. Is there an elegant way to limit the Qt window in one screen?

---

Update:

I don't want the window do a long distance jump back to the screen. So the perfect solution for me is intercepting the movement before it happens. But I could not find a way to do it.

I did a little change to moveEvent(), setting mouse position instead of setting widget's position. Now it doesn't flicker that badly.

```
    auto screenNumber = QApplication::desktop()->screenNumber(this->currentHead());
    if (screenNumber >= 0)
    {
        QScreen * screen = QApplication::screens().at(screenNumber);
        auto screenRect = screen->geometry();
        auto mousePosition = QCursor::pos();

        if (!screenRect.contains(mousePosition))
        {
            mousePosition.setX(std::max(screenRect.left(),
                std::min(mousePosition.x(), screenRect.right())));
            mousePosition.setY(std::max(screenRect.top(),
                std::min(mousePosition.y(), screenRect.bottom())));
            QCursor::setPos(mousePosition);
        }
    }
```

---

Original Post:

1. I've tried to implement my own moveEvent() but the result was very ugly. The window flickered badly. And I think calling resize() in moveEvent() is not good practice.
2. Since I dragged the title bar, there was no mouse move events passing to the window.

code

```
void Cmr42DockWidget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent * event)
{
    if (isVisible() && isFloating())
    {
        auto screenNumber = QApplication::desktop()->screenNumber(this->currentHead());
        if (screenNumber >= 0)
        {
            QScreen * screen = QApplication::screens().at(screenNumber);
            auto rect = geometry();
            auto screenRect = screen->geometry();
            if (!screenRect.contains(rect))
            {
                if (rect.left() < screenRect.left())
                {
                    rect.moveLeft(screenRect.left() - 1);
                }
                if (rect.right() > screenRect.right())
                {
                    rect.moveRight(screenRect.right() - 1);
                }
                if (rect.top() < screenRect.top())
                {
                    rect.moveTop(screenRect.top() + 1);
                }
                if (rect.bottom() > screenRect.bottom())
                {
                    rect.moveBottom(screenRect.bottom() + 1);
                }
                setGeometry(rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user can do the drag, then it is probably a bad idea to prevent the user from doing it, from usability point of view.  I mean, then the user probably has option to disable and enable screens at will and use that to bypass your prevention measures. Why would you want to force the user to jump through such hoops, do you have a compelling reason?

Comment: @hyde  Yeah. This is just a quick and dirty workaround for a UI design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listening for the move event, just hook up to the [screenChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#screenChanged) signal exposed by QWindow.  When the screen changes, snap it back to original monitor.

Be advised - "screen" can change for all kinds of reasons.  The most common is that the user undocked his laptop from a projector or external monitor.  So make sure you always move the window back to an available screen.